# how to find second largest index of arraylist in java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have to write a method that returns the second largest index of an ArrayList of integer values.

The array list is:
4 8 15 16 23 42 97 56 95 85 63 41 52 99 97 Q

The Q is there to mark the end of the input. I am using fileIn.hasNextInt() to read the input and check to see if it is an integer.

The problem I am having with my logic is it is only cycling through the ArrayList and returning the last index of the ArrayList and not the index of the second largest value.

Here is my code:

```
    public static int secondMaxIndex(ArrayList<Integer> intArray){
        int largest  = intArray.get(0);
        int largest2 = intArray.get(0);
        int maxIndex2 = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i <= intArray.size() - 1; i++){
            if( largest < intArray.get(i) ){
                largest = intArray.get(i);
            }
        }
        for( int j = 0; j <= intArray.size() - 1; j++){
            if( intArray.get(j) < largest ){
                maxIndex2 = j;
            }
        }
        return maxIndex2;
    }
```

Comment: Nice use of the Lost numbers. =)

Comment: Your second for loop is iterating the entire array and returning the last value which is smaller than the largest already found in the first loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public static int secondMaxIndex(ArrayList<Integer> intArray)
  {
    int largest  = intArray.get(0);
    Integer largest2 = null;
    int maxIndex = 0;
    int maxIndex2 = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < intArray.size() ; i++)
    {
        if( largest < intArray.get(i) )
        {
            largest2 = largest;
            maxIndex2 = maxIndex;
            largest = intArray.get(i);
            maxIndex = i;
        }
        else if(largest2 == null || intArray.get(i) > largest2)
        {
             largest2 = intArray.get(i);
             maxIndex2 = i;
        }
    }

    return maxIndex2;
}
```

Comment: this does not work for the arraylist: 99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92 91 90 Q

Comment: Ups sorry you are right just initialize second largest as 0 if all the numbers are positive

Comment: Or an easier way you can set it to null and before the else if statement have an other else if where you assign it to getindex(I) if largest2 is null

Comment: so just say largest2 = 0; at the beginning? and then add else if( largest2 == 0 ){largest2 = intArray.get(i);} before the else if statement? since largest2 is an int i cant set it to null

Comment: I updated the code. I also noticed that in the first if statement i wasnt updating the second largest. I cant run it at work but let me know if you need something else.

Keep in mind that largest2 is an Integer not an int. The reason is that primitives cant be null

Answer (score 3):

You are inventing a wheel.
`ArrayList<Integer> intArray` contains `Integers` by contract, no need to verify its elements.
Just use natural sorting and pick second item from the end:

```
intArray.sort(Integer::compare);
return intArray.get(intArray.size - 2);
```

Comment: would this work if there are repeated numbers in the array?

Comment: No it wouldn't this just sorts and gets the second from the last

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( intArray.get(j) < largest ) {
    maxIndex2 = j;
}
```

Here is your problem. Think about it, this code won't just return the second largest, it will return a number that is smaller than the largest number.

Comment: I don't know what value to set as a lower bound to obatin the value I am looking for between the largest and second largest value in the arraylist.